# Execute an external executable within the same process space in C++

Tags: c++, windows, process, ipc, system

I'm trying to find an easy way to execute a java vm in windows using a C++ wrapper. I can use `CreateProcess()` to launch java.exe directly with all of my parameters that I need to give it. The problem is this now shows up as two processes in process manager. So, if I kill the parent process, the java.exe instance still sticks around.

The reason I need to do this is that we have a few java programs, all of which will be running concurrently. I want to be able to give them distinguishable names in the process explorer, so that if a user has trouble with one of them, they don't have to guess which java.exe process that corresponds to.

Comment: You cannot execute a batch file within the same process, period. You probably can, however, run a Java VM in the same process. Edit the title accordingly...

Comment: Done, it seems though that the shell is just a command interpreter - i.e. another executable. So why wouldn't I be able to launch it in the same process space?

Comment: Because a process, in Windows, is associated with an executable file one-to-one. There's no equivalent to the exec() call that loads another executable into the same process. DLLs are a different matter. The command interpreter is not a DLL, however - it's an EXE. Cmd.exe, to be precise.

Comment: You've answered yourself. :) The shell is **another executable**. Well, there might be some legacy way to do this (as in the DOS days), but in Windows you generally load a stand-alone (non-DLL) executable in its own process space. You may put the creating process on-hold and wait for the child-process, but the new process will still show as a new process in the task manager. Check it yourself: run cmd.exe and launch a command-line executable from there.

Comment: No, I believe you. I'm just trying to better understand the reasoning. I come from a linux world where this seems like an easy (easier maybe) thing to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace java.exe with your own executable.  [This article from the Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html) discusses how java.exe works and where to find the source for it.  It's possible that you could get by simply by copying and then renaming java.exe

Comment: So you're advocating embedding the java.exe source code into my executable, and simply calling this instead? It seems like there should be an easier way to accomplish this same task... Basically, all I'm asking for is a java launcher.

Comment: How about my second suggestion (copy and rename java.exe)?

Comment: BTW, in case you didn't read the referenced article, java.exe is simply a java launcher.

Comment: I did read through the link... but it didn't really help me. I'm looking more for a guide on how to load the jvm.dll from within a C++ application.

Comment: Your second suggestion wouldn't be something that we can use... we have roughly 25 java apps that we utilize, and we wanted a more general solution than simply renaming the java.exe executable for each one. Thanks, though.

Comment: That's what java.exe does.  The article tells you where to find the source code.

Comment: you don't need to copy and rename it. Just create 25 hardlinks.

Comment: It does say `If you are curious how java.exe works, you can examine the c source code for launcher/java.c in src.zip. You can see how it finds the correct JVM to load.` So, does src.zip refer to the jdk source? Because there isn't a link to this zip file on the page that I found.

Comment: There are also third party Java launchers such as [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/) and [Janel](http://www.redskaper.com/)